# Real Analysis - Uniform Convergence of a Function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

I am given that:

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $f_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$f_n(x)=\frac{x^{4n}}{4+x^{4n}}.$$

I need to determine whether the sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

This is what I have done:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^{4n}}{4+x^{4n}}=
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if}\ |x|<1 \\
      1, & \text{if}\ |x|\geq1 
    \end{cases}\\
\\ &\implies f(x)=\begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if}\ |x|<1 \\
      1, & \text{if}\ |x|\geq1 
    \end{cases}
\end{align}

So the first case would be when $|x|<1$:

\begin{align}
\sup_{|x|<1}\left| f_n(x)-f(x) \right|&=\sup_{|x|<1}\left| f_n(x) \right| \\
&=\sup_{|x|<1} \left| \frac{x^{4n}}{4+x^{4n}} \right| \\
&\to 0 \ \text{as} \ n \to \infty.
\end{align}

And the second case would be when $|x|\geq1$:

\begin{align}
\sup_{|x|\geq 1}\left| f_n(x)-f(x) \right| &=\sup_{|x|\geq 1} \left| \frac{x^{4n}}{4+x^{4n}} -1 \right| \\
&=\sup_{|x| \geq 1} \left| \frac{-4}{4+x^{4n}} \right| \\
&\to 0 \ \text{as} \ n \to \infty.
\end{align}

So to conclude, as $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left| f_n(x)-f(x) \right|\to 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \left| \frac{-4}{4+x^{4n}} \right|=\frac45$. the sup is at $x=\pm1$ which is in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say @Claudeh5

Comment: you have a problem for f(1).

Comment: $\sup_{x \ge 1} \left| \frac{-4}{4+x^{4n}} \right|=\frac45$

Comment: So this would mean that it doesn't converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $f_n(\pm1) = \frac{ (\pm1)^{4n}}{4+(\pm1)^{4n}} = \frac{1}{5}$ for all $n \ge 0$.

Comment: Yes. The series don't converge  for x=1 to f(1) so the seriezs don't uniformily converge to f(x)

Answer (score 1):

The $f_n$ are continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$, but the poinwise limit of $f_n(x)$ is not, since the uniform convergence preserve the continuity you can conclude that $f_n$ can't converge uniformly on all $\mathbb{R}$.